# How to use aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast,
       CASE 
            WHEN io1.Code = '33' THEN SUM(idd.Qty)
            ELSE SUM(0)
       END                               AS Qty_BackSale,
       CASE 
            WHEN io1.Code = '41' THEN SUM(idd.Qty)
            ELSE SUM(0)
       END                               AS Qty_Stock
FROM   dbo.saleDocuments
       INNER JOIN dbo.saleDocumentDetails
            ON  dbo.saleDocuments.ID = dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.invDocumentDetails   AS  idd
            ON  dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID = idd.saleDocumentDetailID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.invDocuments  AS id2
            ON  id2.ID = idd.invDocumentID
       LEFT JOIN dbo.invOperations       AS io1
            ON  (io1.ID = id2.invOperationID)
WHERE  (dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID = 1295617)
GROUP BY
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast,
       io1.Code
```

its result is:

[image]

I would like to achieve:

[image]

How should I change the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned JRLambert, move `SUM()` outside `CASE`, and remove `io1.Code` from `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

Move the `SUM()` in your `CASE` statements outside of the `CASE`:

```
   SELECT 
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays,
       dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast,
       SUM(CASE 
            WHEN io1.Code = '33' THEN idd.Qty
            ELSE 0
       END)                              AS Qty_BackSale,
       SUM(CASE 
            WHEN io1.Code = '41' THEN idd.Qty
            ELSE 0
       END)                              AS Qty_Stock
   FROM
       dbo.saleDocuments
       INNER JOIN dbo.saleDocumentDetails
           ON  dbo.saleDocuments.ID = dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.invDocumentDetails   AS  idd
           ON  dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID = idd.saleDocumentDetailID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.invDocuments  AS id2
           ON  id2.ID = idd.invDocumentID
       LEFT JOIN dbo.invOperations       AS io1
           ON  (io1.ID = id2.invOperationID)
WHERE
    (dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID = 1295617)
GROUP BY
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.DocumentID,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.invProductID,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Qty,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.QtyConfirmed,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountPrice,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountUserPrice,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.AmountCost,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.RespiteDays,
    dbo.saleDocumentDetails.Date_UpdateLast,
    io1.Code;
```

Comment: Thanks, it is needed to remove `io1.Code` from group by.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove group by dbo.saleDocumentDetails.ID ?

Comment: He needs to keep that.

Comment: Yes. but all of the columns are same except the two last columns.